# How do you do signed 32bit widening multiplication on SSE2?

Tags: assembly, sse, simd, webassembly, sse2

This question came up when reviewing the WebAssembly SIMD proposal for extended multiplication.

To support older hardware, we need to support SSE2 and the only vector multiplication operation for 32 bit integers is [`pmuludq`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmuludq).  (Signed [`pmuldq`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmuldq) was only added in SSE4.1)

(non-widening is relatively easy; shuffle to feed 2x `pmuludq` and take the low halves of the 4 results to emulate SSE4.1 `pmulld`).

Comment: Note that SSE4.1 added [`pmuldq`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmuldq) widening *signed* multiplication.  So it exists, but you're correct that it's not part of SSE2 and thus not baseline for x86-64 :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mulhs(a, b) = mulhu(a, b) - (a < 0 ? b : 0) - (b < 0 ? a : 0)`

Using that, two signed double-width products can be computed like this,

```
__m128i mul_epi32(__m128i a, __m128i b) {
    a = _mm_shuffle_epi32(a, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 1, 1, 0));
    b = _mm_shuffle_epi32(b, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 1, 1, 0));
    __m128i unsignedProduct = _mm_mul_epu32(a, b);
    __m128i threshold = _mm_set_epi32(INT_MIN, 0, INT_MIN, 0);
    __m128i signA = _mm_cmplt_epi32(a, threshold);
    __m128i signB = _mm_cmplt_epi32(b, threshold);
    __m128i x = _mm_shuffle_epi32(_mm_and_si128(signA, b), _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 3, 0, 1));
    __m128i y = _mm_shuffle_epi32(_mm_and_si128(signB, a), _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 3, 0, 1));
    return _mm_sub_epi32(_mm_sub_epi32(unsignedProduct, x), y);
}
```

That saves a couple of operations over the other proposal, but it's very close and now it includes a load which could be bad if this code is cold.

Comment: I think the requirements we have are that it outputs in the same order as the original.  pmuludq does the same even laned stuff you're talking about.  The shuffles in my version exist to adjust for the requirements of the standard.  If you add in the shuffles for yours, does it perform any better or differently?

Comment: @DanWeber it still shaves off two instructions, but I didn't benchmark anything

Comment: If you look at Clang's assembly version (it's on the godbolt), it managed to shave off 1 shuffle op off of mine, though I'm not totally sure I understand what it did.

Comment: `threshold` can be generated on the fly in 2 instructions: `pcmpeqd xmm0, xmm0` (all ones) / `psllq xmm0, 63` to leave just the sign bit set in each qword half.  Compilers will still just load a constant, but if you're JITing and want to avoid a load, you can do that, @DanWeber.  Good if you want to hoist out of a loop, otherwise probably load a constant instead of spending more vector-ALU instructions to regenerate it every time.

Comment: Can you usefully get the `a<0` mask with `psrad` arithmetic right shift?

Comment: @PeterCordes I tried using `psrad` first, but then I needed extra `pand` to zero out the odd lanes, so that didn't seem like a good deal

Comment: @PeterCordes there's no `psubq` here though, only the top half of the product needs the fixup (but that also means that the bottom half must be left alone, which is a complicating factor)

Comment: Oh, right, of course the low halves are already correct, that's how multiply works.  Now I understand that `mulhs` is the high-half product and that expression is just showing the high-half fixups.  Brain fart on my end, I see now why `psubq` isn't needed.

Comment: @PeterCordes could the optimization using psubq in the comparison thread also work here?

Answer (score 0):

### Big shout out to @GeDaMo on ##asm for helping come up with this solution.

### [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/WGa1ba)

### C/C++:

```cpp
#include <xmmintrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <tmmintrin.h>
#include <smmintrin.h>
#include <cstdio>

typedef int32_t int32x4_t __attribute__((vector_size(16))) __attribute__((aligned(16)));
typedef int64_t int64x2_t __attribute__((vector_size(16))) __attribute__((aligned(16)));

int64x2_t multiply32_low_s(int32x4_t a, int32x4_t b) {
    auto aSigns = a >> 31;
    auto bSigns = b >> 31;
    auto aInt = a ^ aSigns;
    aInt -= aSigns;
    auto bInt = b ^ bSigns;
    bInt -= bSigns;
    const auto shuffleMask = _MM_SHUFFLE(1,1,0,0);
    auto absProd = _mm_mul_epu32(_mm_shuffle_epi32((__m128i)aInt, shuffleMask), _mm_shuffle_epi32((__m128i)bInt, shuffleMask));
    auto aSignsInt = _mm_shuffle_epi32((__m128i)aSigns, shuffleMask);
    auto bSignsInt = _mm_shuffle_epi32((__m128i)bSigns,shuffleMask);
    auto prodSigns = aSignsInt ^ bSignsInt;
    absProd ^= prodSigns;
    absProd -= prodSigns;
    return (int64x2_t)absProd;
}

int64x2_t multiply32_high_s(int32x4_t a, int32x4_t b) {
    auto aSigns = a >> 31;
    auto bSigns = b >> 31;
    auto aInt = a ^ aSigns;
    aInt -= aSigns;
    auto bInt = b ^ bSigns;
    bInt -= bSigns;
    const auto shuffleMask = _MM_SHUFFLE(3,3,2,2);
    auto absProd = _mm_mul_epu32(_mm_shuffle_epi32((__m128i)aInt, shuffleMask), _mm_shuffle_epi32((__m128i)bInt, shuffleMask));
    auto aSignsInt = _mm_shuffle_epi32((__m128i)aSigns, shuffleMask);
    auto bSignsInt = _mm_shuffle_epi32((__m128i)bSigns,shuffleMask);
    auto prodSigns = aSignsInt ^ bSignsInt;
    absProd ^= prodSigns;
    absProd -= prodSigns;
    return (int64x2_t)absProd;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int32x4_t a{-5,500,-5000,50000};
    int32x4_t b{10,-100,-5000,500000000};
    auto c = multiply32_low_s(a,b);
    auto d = multiply32_high_s(a,b);
    printf("%ld %ld\n", c[0],c[1]);
    printf("%ld %ld\n", d[0],d[1]);
}
```

### Assembly

```
multiply32_low_s(int __vector(4), int __vector(4)):
 movdqa xmm3,xmm0
 movdqa xmm2,xmm1
 psrad  xmm3,0x1f
 psrad  xmm2,0x1f
 pxor   xmm0,xmm3
 pxor   xmm1,xmm2
 psubd  xmm1,xmm2
 psubd  xmm0,xmm3
 pshufd xmm2,xmm2,0x50
 pshufd xmm1,xmm1,0x50
 pshufd xmm0,xmm0,0x50
 pshufd xmm3,xmm3,0x50
 pmuludq xmm0,xmm1
 pxor   xmm2,xmm3
 pxor   xmm0,xmm2
 psubq  xmm0,xmm2
 ret    
 nop    WORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
multiply32_high_s(int __vector(4), int __vector(4)):
 movdqa xmm3,xmm0
 movdqa xmm2,xmm1
 psrad  xmm3,0x1f
 psrad  xmm2,0x1f
 pxor   xmm0,xmm3
 pxor   xmm1,xmm2
 psubd  xmm1,xmm2
 psubd  xmm0,xmm3
 pshufd xmm2,xmm2,0xfa
 pshufd xmm1,xmm1,0xfa
 pshufd xmm0,xmm0,0xfa
 pshufd xmm3,xmm3,0xfa
 pmuludq xmm0,xmm1
 pxor   xmm2,xmm3
 pxor   xmm0,xmm2
 psubq  xmm0,xmm2
 ret    
 nop    WORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
```

Comment: Is this even worth doing? A scalar fallback looks relatively promising..

Comment: That's a great question.  I'd love to hear feedback on it.

Comment: @harold: Probably the only reason to do this much vector work (even with your optimized version) is if it's really useful to have the result in vectors, and the input started in vector regs.  i.e. as a processing step between SIMD operations, not on its own.  Maybe not even then; https://godbolt.org/z/MWY8hq shows it's 16 instructions, and CPUs too old for SSE4.1 don't have mov-elimination of xor-elimination.  K10 and Core2 do at least have 128-bit wide vector ALUs; earlier CPUs don't, making those vector insns even more expensive.

Comment: So yeah, movq/shuffle/movq or store / load to feed some scalar `imul r64,r64` (or maybe `imul r32` on CPUs with slow 64-bit integer multiply) is probably good even if we have to eat a store-forwarding stall to get back into vectors.  (4x scalar stores + vector load might be better throughput than 4x movd + 3x punpck, if we used 32-bit imul so the result is split across 4 regs.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm seriously wondering why we're supporting sse2 for wasm. My guess is that v8 needs the assembly for the scalar variants when they're applicable.

Comment: SSE2 is baseline for x86-64, so being able to handle just that means you can run on *any* x86-64 system, without having to make decisions about what CPUs are too old.  For some things, SSE2 is perfectly fine, e.g. vertical SIMD with float or double, or byte or word integers.  If wasm doesn't have a way for applications to detect that the kind of SIMD they want to do would be slower than scalar, that's problematic, but denying SIMD entirely might be a worse problem for other uses.  (Native x86 code can check on that, and choose on a per-function basis by setting function pointers.)

Comment: Requiring SSSE3 covers first-gen Core 2, like 2007.  So I can see some argument for just requiring SSE4.1 at least.  CPUs that old will have a hard time running modern web browsers.

Comment: I made a similar argument that saying that Nehalem was almost 12.  We do dynamically detect instruction sets, and I think I've gotten to the bottom of why you saw vex instructions mixed with non vex. The V8 compiler matches an intrinsic based on whether or not a higher order instruction set is defined. For instance, if someone wrote something and said it would work with ssse3 and higher and they never wrote the avx variant, it would be non-vex.